# Putting Values from JSON to High Charts

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I have a problem with High Charts, I want to show chart to show details from this example JSON data

`[{"eventName":"ABC","countError":147391},"eventName":"DEF","countError":117926}]`

The JSON code itself only consist 2 parameters which are **eventName** and **count error.**

The code that i use is divided into AJAX function:

```
function getSumErrorSummary(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'ErrorSummaryServlet',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);    
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Cannot getting Error Summary Servlet," + textStatus.toString());
            },
        });
    }
```

Then I put the array in objects using this code `var objects = [];`

Then I call the AJAX function using this logic:

```
getSumErrorSummary(function(data){
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        //console.log([item.eventName, item.countError]);
        console.log("starting...");
        objects.push([item.eventName, item.countError]);
        console.log("done");
    })
});

var options = {
    chart : {
        type : 'column',
        margin : 75,
        options3d : {
            enabled : true,
            alpha : 10,
            beta : 25,
            depth : 70
        }
    },
    title : {
        text : 'Subtotal Error Summary'
    },
    plotOptions : {
        column : {
            depth : 25
        }
    },
    xAxis : {
        title :{
            text: 'Names'
        }
    },
    yAxis : {
        title : {
            text : 'Sub total'
        }
    },
    series : [{
        data: objects,
        name: 'Click Error'
    }]
}

$('#flot-line-chart').highcharts(options);
```

I have initialized the function for each of the data is pushed to an array called objects. Then every objects is put into the highcharts data series. But the charts showing nothing unless the x, y label and the series name.

Any ideas? Kindly help to advise.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I change the code into this:

```
getSumErrorSummary(function(data){
         console.log("starting...");
          $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                //console.log([item.eventName, item.countError]);
                objects.push(data.map(function (d, i) {
                    return { name: d.eventName, data: [d.countError] };
                }));
            })
        console.log("done");
    });
```

but in console log debugger, it shows empty `[]`.

Comment: Try parsing your counterror field to integer  or after you get data from AJAX call try parsing it into JSON using  var json = $.parseJSON(data); Just a guess!

Comment: Update 1 function is so wrong, your looping 2 times and no need to push in to object, `map` function returns array of objects which you want. check my updated answer.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, that means you need to create chart **inside** callback. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your JSON data should be like

```
[{ name: 'ABC', data: [147391] }, { name: 'DEF', data: [117926] }]
```

**OR** if you dont want to change it, use this function to create object

**UPDATE**

```
var options = {
    chart : {
      ......
    series : []  //no data while initializing
};

getSumErrorSummary(function(data) {
    console.log(object) // undefined
    var object = data.map(function(d, i) { 
                return { name: d.eventName, data: [d.countError] }; 
             });
    console.log(object); //[{ name: ... }]

    //set object to options
    options.series = object;

    // call your chart function here
    $('#flot-line-chart').highcharts(options);
});
```

check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9akLyc4L/2/)**    **(Updated)**

Comment: hi still no luck, i have already mapped the data into the call back function. please see UPDATE 1. thanks

Comment: i i have already put the `$('#flot-line-chart').highcharts(options);` like your updates but the charts still not showing.